# How do I handle and/or repopulate checkbox group(s)?

Tags: plugin-development, checkboxes

I have a contact form (public facing only) on my site that has a checkbox group. The user can pick their favorite color(s). Upon successful submission I am capturing that data within the CP via a plugin.

I have a checkbox field within the CP called "colors".

This is how I am outputting the values in my template:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name"class="form-control" value="{% if contact is defined %}{{ contact.name }}{% endif %}" placeholder="Full Name"/>
{{ contact is defined and contact ? errorList(contact.getErrors('name')) }}

....

{% for option in craft.fields.getFieldByHandle('colors').getFieldType.options %}
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="fields[colors][]" value="{{ option.value }}">{{ option.label }}
    </label>
</div>
{% endfor %}
....
```

So far so good. Name is required, so if a user submits the form without entering a name, but has chosen a few colors, I would like the colors to be checked when the page reloads. I am able to do that on the `name` field easily.

The next part of the question, how do I handle the array of options via my plugin?

Here is what I have in my controller:

**ContactFormController**

```
....
$contact->profession = craft()->request->getPost('profession[]');
```

When I log what the model is getting here is what I am seeing:

```
[name] => My Name
[colors] =>
....
```

I assume that I will also need to set up a FK relationship in my record file so once the form is submitted I can have a 1:many relationship. I'll look at the docs on how to set that up - and post what I've done back for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to follow up with this thread in case someone else came across this. If there is a better solution, let me know and I will update the answer accordingly.

Using the example above, the user filling out the form can choose their favorite color(s).

I should mention that the `colors` checkbox field was created in the CP, and all values for the checkbox are managed there. That way I can easily loop through the values within my template.

**twig/html**

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    {% for option in craft.fields.getFieldByHandle('colors').getFieldType.options %}
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="{{ option.value }}" name="fields[colors][]" {% if account is defined and option.value in account.colors %}checked{% endif %}>{{ option.label }}
           </label>
        </div>
   {% endfor %}
   {% if account is defined %}
       {{ errorList(account.getErrors('colors')) }}
   {% endif %}
</div>
```